# How can I set a transparancy color for a div? It should work in both Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I used the following code in my project.

```
#tooltip
{
position:absolute;
z-index:3000;
border:1px solid black;
background-color:/*#FFF8E9*/#F2F2F2;
padding:5px;
width:300px;
opacity:0.2;
filter:alpha(opacity=20);
}
```

It is working fine in Firefox.  But it does not work in IE.  How to solve?

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
filter:alpha(opacity=20);
```

As Chrome and FF read the rgba values and IE will pick up the filter property :)

Answer (score 1):

```
filter:alpha(opacity=20);
opacity: 0.2;
-moz-opacity:0.2;
```

Should work for all browsers.  Can you show us a live example if this doesn't work?  Also as a comment:

```
backgroundcolor:/*#FFF8E9*/#F2F2F2;
```

Try changing this to

```
background-color:#F2F2F2;
```

IE might not interptet comments used in this fashion, also it should have a hyphen.

http://www.domedia.org/oveklykken/css-transparency.php

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for EVERY browser that supports transparency:

```
.transparent_class {
        filter:alpha(opacity=50);
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
        opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**opacity: 0.5;** This is the "most important" one because it is the current standard in CSS. 
This will work in most versions of Firefox, Safari, and Opera. This would be all you need if all browsers supported current standards. Which, of course, they don't.

**filter:alpha(opacity=50);** This one you need for IE.

**-moz-opacity:0.5;** You need this one to support way old school versions of the Mozilla browsers like Netscape Navigator.

**-khtml-opacity: 0.5;** This is for way old versions of Safari (1.x) when the rendering engine it was using was still referred to as KTHML, as opposed to the current